# What (semi-) permanent infrastructure be added to ESD harden an already-constructed space?

Tags: esd

I have a newly-constructed university center which I would like to harden to ESD. Unfortunately, I became involved in the process too late to ensure that proper antistatic flooring was installed. At this stage, nothing can be replaced, but things can be added.

As it's an open university space, there is little I can do to control how users, i.e. students, proactively protect things against ESD. The only thing I can do is load the dice in their favor.

At the very least, I will put antistatic mats on electronics benches, but it's unlikely that students will know about wearing a wristband, and it's even more unlikely they will do it.

What other (semi-)permanent infrastructure can I add to generally harden the room?

Comment: The best thing you can do is train folk so that they do use the ESD prevention equipment (else, why are you embarking on something that may be totally ineffective?).

Comment: You could also buy a bunch of ESD flip flops and force everyone to wear them while inside the room. Which you would have to do with ESD flooring anyway, or otherwise it would be pretty useless.

Comment: It's also common to install air moisturizers to counter ESD. These could be anything from the cheapest stuff you can buy in a hardware store to some industrial thing hooked to the water pipes. All depending on budget and room size.

Comment: I would not recommend to buy loose ESD mats to place underneath chairs though. We had this at work and they tended to leave nasty marks and scratches on the floor underneath, when dust gets caught between the floor and the mat.

Comment: Keep relative humidity above 50%

Comment: If this is an instructional lab, then just have the TA's mark off if a student doesn't test their wristband at the start of each lab session, or is caught touching equipment/components without their wristband.

Comment: @ThePhoton it's not an instructional lab, and even if it were, that's just not how (American) universities work. Students have a lot of freedom, and some of that is to do dumb things and destroy the circuits they're working on.

Comment: @KennSebesta, I am an American (with 3 degrees from American universities) and even here part of the purpose of lab courses is to teach good lab practice. Admittedly that tradition is stronger in other disciplines (chemistry, biology, ...) but it should also be part of EE as well. Destroying a few 4000-series CMOS chips might be a reasonable way to teach that. Destroying a $50,000 or $500,000 VNA shouldn't be. (Even damaging equipment so it has to be sent for repair will deprive other students of the chance to use it that term)

Comment: Also after working in industry for many years, I wish the universities would produce graduates with better lab discipline...ESD damage to a prototype can cause weeks of extra work debugging the problem and proving it was not caused in the factory, even if the device itself is only worth a few cents.

Comment: @ThePhoton awesome, then you fully get how the trend is toward increasingly open environments that encourage people to learn cross-disciplinary skills. Please note, this is a center, not a lab, so the expectations and users are a little different. Agreed 100% on the knock-on effects of a failure, although that has to be weighed against the friction of taking too many precautions. The awesome thing about the Arduino Uno is how stupidly idiot-proof it is, and forcing people to wear ESD while programming it would border on the absurd, perhaps even paranoia.

Comment: @Kenn this is the first time you mentioned Arduino's. Up till now we didn't know if you were doing RF measurements with million dollar equipment or programming $20 SBC's. If you include this information in the question you might get answers that are more helpful.

Comment: I'm getting great answers, thanks. Whether it's an Arduino or a very expensive robot (it's tough to say what students will bring, so let's not count out either), it's a bit of a distraction to learning what levers can be pulled and dials can be turned to generally harden a room.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can combat ESD. I would definately have these:

- Wrist strap with detector (sends a signal to make sure you are strapped in). Properly ground for saftey with 1MegΩ resistor (especially working with dangerous voltages over ~60V)
- ESD bench surface, either use a mat or get a bench with an ESD surface and ground it
- ESD lab coat (clothing and other materials can generate thousands of volts when triboelectrically charged)

These are nice to have:

- ionizer (ionized air conducts fields better, these can be pricey for some)
- humidifier (controlled humidity is better but if your in a dry climate any humidity is good)
- ESD flooring and grounding straps

I would weigh any ESD control costs against those of the failure of the project. Example: if you are developing 30$-100$ boards then it doesn't make a lot of sense to drop 10k$+ on esd control (just make more boards). If the boards are thousands of dollars then the calculation changes.

Applications like medical and aerospace cannot tolerate any type of failure so more ESD control is better.

Here are some aerospace requirements:
http://everyspec.com/NASA/NASA-JPL/JPL-D-1348_Rev_F_6554/

Comment: Agreed 100% on the cost v. benefit calc. In my center, the only things at risk are the personal projects the students are working on. It's their business to decide how much it's worth to them to protect against ESD. I will caution them that the stove is hot, and they will learn on their own time. Still, it's nice to take simple measures to make it harder to get burnt, you know?

Answer (score 1):

The bench top mats are the best bang-for-your-buck. The purpose of static-dissipating mats and wrist straps are to bring the worker and workpiece to the same potential, not necessarily to ground.

The use of static dissipating mats on the benches is very effective. When a workpiece is set on the mat, the worker-workpiece potential difference is already zero.

When the worker walks away and returns, touching the mat first will safely equalize the potential with the workpiece, even if the mat is not grounded.

But the OP asked, “What else?”.

1. Obvious signage declaring 1) to touch the mat first. 2)to indicate the presence of wrist strap connectors.3)to entreat the workers to use them.
2. Make the wrist-strap connections obvious.
3. Have a supply of wrist straps available (free??).
4. Any exposed metal within reach of the bench should be covered with insulating or static dissipating material.

Grounding the mats through a 1 mega ohm resistance is desirable to equalize the mats to the same voltage as the surroundings, but is not strictly necessary.